# Toggle input visibility on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two buttons and two input fields, the input fields are hidden what i want to do is to toggle the display property on click but it only works once, and i have a close button next to each input this close button should remove each input on click, here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
       $('.btn1').click(function() {
         $('.input1').css('display','block');
       });
   });

   $(function() {
          $('.btn2').click(function() {
            $('.input2').css('display','block');
          });
      });
      
   $(".closebutton").click(function () {
             $("input").remove('.removediv');
           });
```

```css
.input1, .input2{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default close">Close button</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input1 removediv">Input 1
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn2">Button2</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default close">Close button</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input2 removediv">Input 2
```

Comment: it works in both cases

Comment: it only ever displays the inputs. Are you asking how to hide them again?

Comment: Use `.toggle()` i.e. `$('.input2').toggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method's

1. Change the `toggle()` instead of `css('display')` property
2. `.closebutton` is wrong selector try `.close` and hide the `next()` input, not all `$('input')` .use `hide()` instead of `remove()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn1').click(function() {
    $('.input1').toggle()
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.btn2').click(function() {
    $('.input2').toggle()
  });
});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $(this).next("input").hide();
});
```

```css
.input1,
.input2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default close">Close button</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input1 removediv">Input 1
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn2">Button2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default close">Close button</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input2 removediv">Input 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle between visible and hidden use `.toggle()`, otherwise all you do on click is show the inputs

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn1, .btn2').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.input1,
.input2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn1">Button1</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input1">Input 1
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn2">Button2</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input2">Input 2
```

I also reduced your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Jquery` toggle option :

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn1').click(function() {
    $('.input1').toggle();
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.btn2').click(function() {
    $('.input2').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
       $('.btn1').click(function() {
         $('.input1').toggle();
       });
   });

   $(function() {
          $('.btn2').click(function() {
            $('.input2').toggle();
          });
      });
```

```css
.input1, .input2{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn1">Button1</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input1">Input 1
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn2">Button2</button> 
<input type="text" class="form-control input2">Input 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
       $('.btn1').click(function() {
         $('.input1').toggle();
      
       });
   });

   $(function() {
          $('.btn2').click(function() {
            $('.input2').toggle();
          });
      });
```

```css
.input1, .input2{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn1">Button1</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control input1">Input 1
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn2">Button2</button> 
<input type="text" class="form-control input2">Input 2
```